# Simplificar localização de valores em arrays no PHP

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho os *arrays* conforme abaixo:

```
$records = [
    ["id"=>"1", "name"=>"Alpha"],
    ["id"=>"2", "name"=>"Bravo"],
    ["id"=>"3", "name"=>"Charlie"],
    ["id"=>"4", "name"=>"Delta"],
    ["id"=>"5", "name"=>"Echo"],
];

$codes = [2,4];
```

Preciso imprimir somente o nomes contidos na variável `$records` correspondentes a cada código da variável `$codes` esperando o resultado:

> Bravo
>
> Delta

Então fiz o seguinte código:

```
foreach ($codes as $i) {
    foreach ($records as $j) {
        if ($i == $j['id']) {
            echo "<p> {$j['name']} </p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de obter o mesmo resultado de forma mais fácil?

Achei ruim da forma que estou fazendo porque para cada código da variável `$codes` eu faço uma varredura completa na variável `$records` comparando os valores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerando que o valor de `id` é único para cada nome, você pode definir um mapa que relaciona o id com o respectivo nome. No PHP, podemos definir esse mapa através de um *array* associativo em que a chave é o id e o valor é o respectivo nome. Podemos montar esse mapa com uma linha de código:

```
$nomes = array_column($records, "name", "id");
```

Isso gerará o *array*:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Alpha
    [2] => Bravo
    [3] => Charlie
    [4] => Delta
    [5] => Echo
)
```

Assim, bastaria acessar as posições `$nomes[2]` e `$nomes[4]`, ou:

```
foreach ($codes as $code) {
    echo $nomes[$code], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Exibindo os nomes desejados.

Comment: Um "correto" e eficiente uso do `array_column` +1

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Poderia utilizar [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para filtrar as informações e [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) para buscar na pesquisa se existe algum código igual, *exemplo*:

```
<?php

$records = [
    ["id"=>"1", "name"=>"Alpha"],
    ["id"=>"2", "name"=>"Bravo"],
    ["id"=>"3", "name"=>"Charlie"],
    ["id"=>"4", "name"=>"Delta"],
    ["id"=>"5", "name"=>"Echo"],
];

$codes = [2,4];


$array_result = array_filter($records, function($item) use ($codes) {
    return in_array($item['id'], $codes);
});


foreach($array_result as $value){
    echo $value['name'];
}
```

[Exemplo ONLINE IDEONE](https://ideone.com/g3HKhT)

Comment: Solucionado @GuilhermeNascimento !!!

Comment: Virgilio Novic show!

Comment: Obrigado amigo! ajudou bastante! +1

Answer (score 4):

Usar `array_filter`+`foreach` e usar `array_search`+`array_column`+`foreach` não é melhor do que o que já fez em sua pergunta, que são apenas 2 foreachs+if, não só de performance, mas até de legibilidade do código, que no código **da pergunta** esta melhor. O uso de array_search, array_filter e outras função nem sempre serão melhores que fazer 1 ou 2 loops, as vezes será a mesma coisa, no caso do exemplo do Anderson, o uso de `array_collunm` foi o mais eficiente falando da função especifica

Ainda sim não necessariamente a forma mais eficiente em geral.

Na maioria das vezes o mais simples é o melhor, e no caso da necessidade do autor da pergunta um `in_array` e um único `foreach` já resolveriam tudo e manteria ainda o código mais legível:

```
$records = [
    ["id"=>"1", "name"=>"Alpha"],
    ["id"=>"2", "name"=>"Bravo"],
    ["id"=>"3", "name"=>"Charlie"],
    ["id"=>"4", "name"=>"Delta"],
    ["id"=>"5", "name"=>"Echo"],
];

$codes = [2,4];

foreach ($records as $j) {
    if (in_array($j['id'], $codes)) {
        echo "<p> {$j['name']} </p>";
    }
}
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/UFXWqO

Comment: Como você tem certeza disso? `array_filter+foreach e usar array_search+array_column+foreach` !!! e outra coisa se os códigos não forem iguais o `array_column` não é eficiente é um erro, então é melhor produzir um código que vai caber em todas as esferas do que achar isso mediante um exemplo da pergunta ...

Comment: Caro @VirgilioNovic array_column foi eficiente no exemplo citado apenas, do Anderson, se os códigos forem diferentes então nem a pergunta do autor faz sentido, concorda? Agora sim, array_filter+foreach é quase a mesma coisa 2 foreachs, não me leve a mal, mas não deixa de ser 2 "loops" ... claro que internamente no primeiro caso, mas de qualquer forma nem precisa de 2 loops, independente da forma que use, a resposta aqui indica justamente isso ... um loop só já resolve.

Comment: a gente analise o código ( foi eficiente no exemplo citado apenas, do Anderson, se os códigos forem diferentes então nem a pergunta do autor faz sentido, concorda ) além do que pergunta isso é uma premissa aqui ... !!! então o `array_column` só eficiente assim se o Id for diferente da ordem o código vai quebrar ...!!!!

Comment: posso concordar com um for mas o resto é um coisa que podemos questionar

Comment: @VirgilioNovic qual resto? A unica parte que falo do uso do array_colunm é uma frase, o resto tudo é sobre não necessariamente os exemplos fornecidos serem melhores ... aliás, eu não disse que array_colunm é o melhor, eu disse que o uso especificamente da forma feita foi a forma eficiente de usar a função e não que é a forma mais eficiente de resolver o problema do autor ... todas respostas usaram coisas a mais ... e a resposta aqui indica que o melhor é usar menos. Tem muita coisa que as pessoas complicam achando que estão facilitando, espero que compreenda.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente sobre o que falaram, mas se aplicando a minha situação o `array_column` serve perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. +1

Comment: @LaércioLopes sim, da forma que o Anderson apresentou imaginei mesmo que caberia melhor para ti, a critica aqui do debate todo foi ao uso indiscriminado de loops e a perda de legibilidade das demais soluções propostas, uma coisa que tem que ter em mente, se é possivel simplificar então realmente não existe motivos para complicar algo ... muitas pessoas no mundo de *Design Patterns* sofrem com a falsa sensação que "complicar" é melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar `array_search` (busca na array) e `array_column` (busca numa coluna específica):

```
foreach ($codes as $i) {
   echo "<p> {$records[array_search($i, array_column($records, 'id'))]['name']} </p>";
}
```

Irá buscar na coluna `id` os valores da array `$codes` e retornar o valor da chave `name`.

O `array_search($i, array_column($records, 'id'))` irá retornar o índice do item na array `$records` onde a chave `id` coincide com os valores da array `$codes`. Seria como:

```
> $records[1]['name']
> $records[3]['name']
```

[Veja no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/bmsZE5)

Só irá funcionar no PHP versão 5.5 em diante por causa do `array_column`.

Comment: Obrigado Sam! +1!